# Android studio always download gradle for every new project?

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I just established Android studio and it always download gradle for every new project and it takes ages to complete the download as connections here are not too strong.
so is there anyway i could manually add the gradle zip into the android studio? so i wont have to download it every time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. First download gradle from https://www.gradle.org/downloads and unzip it to a local folder.

Then on Android Studio, go to Preferences -> Gradle and switch from "Use default gradle wrapper (recommended)" or "Use customizable gradle wrapper" to "Use local gradle distribution" and point to the folder where you've installed gradle and Android Studio won't try to download it every single time.

Comment: Actually, starting with Android Studio 1.0.0 it comes with its own local Gradle distribution, currently version 2.2.1 so there is no need to download gradle yourself.