# Install Gradle and its dependencies once for all Android projects

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Every time I create/open a new Android project, I have to wait 5 - 10 minutes for Android Studio to download Gradle and its dependencies and configure the project, even though this is usually the exact same process for every project.

[Android studio always download gradle for every new project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27394238/android-studio-always-download-gradle-for-every-new-project) discusses rectifying this for a single project, but is there some way to set this all up **once** for **all** projects created in the future? MTIA!

EDIT: Just realised it would probably help to specify the version of Android Studio that I'm using, which is Arctic Fox 2020.3.1 Patch 1.

Answer (score 0):

It does that to make sure you have the latest version of Gradle. Here is the way around it. Of course you may want to change the version number at the end but you get the idea.

1.- When you're opening a file on the option Gradle project: select the build.gradle that cames on your project

2.- Select the option "Use local grade distribution" and in Gradle home option; go and select in C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\gradle-2.2.1

Comment: Thanks for answering but if you're talking about the settings provided under "Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle", I'm already aware of those as they're mentioned in the linked question. I want a global solution for **all** projects that can be configured once and forgotten about. Is this possible?

Comment: Hmm...yeah I guess that would work, but I still wouldn't call that optimal. Anyway thanks for the tips :-)

Comment: I was searching for the same, there is no such option.